# Sent and Received text messages that I didn’t send or receive

Tags: privacy, iphone

I reviewed my usage detail for my iPhone 6S today online and it shows 3 texts sent from my phone late at night and shortly thereafter it shows that I received four, which I never did.

I contacted Bell and they see the texts but cannot explain why. I was sleeping at the time and nobody had access to my phone, I was home by myself.

Is it possible that someone could have hacked my phone, like an ex, and sent the texts and deleted the ones I received? I’ve read about people being able to have access to your phone without actually physically having the phone.

Note that at one time my phone was left unattended and could have been compromised.

Comment: Is your iMessage account attached to any other devices? Computer, iPad etc..

Comment: No, it’s not connected to any other devices.

Comment: Then in all likelihood, your account was probably compromised and being utilized in a phishing campaign. Change all passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible an iPhone can get hacked to send and receive messages and delete them as well.

It's also possible somebody linked your iMessage account to another device so check what devices are authorized.

Otherwise reset all passwords. Enable 2FA/MFA where possible. Update IOS to the latest version. Uninstall any recently installed apps. Update any existing apps to the latest version. If it happens again restore the phone to factory defaults.